# Time Stamp in DBML is solving concurrency issues...why?

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, timestamp, datacontext

We use `LINQ` in our `ASP .NET` application to run database queries and commands. We have been having concurrency issues on updates to tables in which we update the value of a `Date` field. More specifically, if two users click a button at the exact same time and the code attempts to update a `Date` field in the database  then the built-in optimistic concurrency fails to do its job and one the users throws an exception.

Here's the weird part, if we go into the `DBML` and set the field's `time stamp` property to true and run the unit tests it works just fine...no explicit locks needed.

We would like to understand this a bit more before implementing this throughout the entire system. Does anyone have some understanding as to why this works?

Comment: I assume by "LINQ in ASP.NET" you mean you're using LINQ to SQL?

Comment: @Baddie - Yes, by LINQ I meant LINQ to SQL. I mentioned ASP.NET because I wanted to specify that this is a web application and therefore can have the issue of multiple concurrent users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your system I would guess that is because SQL Server DATETIME has a resolution of 3 ms at best, giving a high probability for conflicts. TIMESTAMP is a counter in desquise and cannot conflict.

Comment: +1 well said! There's nothing but TIMESTAMP (or ROWVERSION in SQL Server 2008 and up) to reliably "version" your SQL Server data rows.

Comment: The "timestamp" setting in the DBML doesn't force or require a TIMESTAMP / ROWVERSION column.

Answer (score 0):

From memory, I believe this is how it works:

The default optimistic transactions ensure that **all** previous values on the row are the same before an UPDATE is allowed.

By setting the "Time Stamp" property to True, you are telling the system that a particular column is auto-generated by the DB, and should be used as the "time stamp type" column.  In other words, if the value of that column alone is the same as it was before the UPDATE, then the UPDATE is allowed.

Since your unit test fails without time stamp enabled for the DateTime column, I'll guess that you're also changing something else on the row, which triggers the conflict.  With time stamp enabled on the DateTime column, the changes happen so close together that they have the same time.

You should be able to verify this behavior using SQL Profiler.

FWIW, I suspect that this actually isn't the behavior you want...